# Why this window is a mess?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

[image: IMG1]
111

#### XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFApp.Root"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="Root" Height="454" Width="392">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Margin="10,10,10,57"/>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="10,386,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Height="42" Width="185"
                Content="TEST BUTTON">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What are you asking about? The reason of broken window layout? Check this `Margin="10,386,0,0"`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It has nothing to do with it. The window must be the same as in editor.

Comment: Make a two row definitions in your grid

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Please, do the calculations and tell me what is not enough for displaying controls? Height? Width?

Comment: Well, this isn't a free code writing service. And there is an answer below showing the solution, you have oversized margin values, it's better to place into separate grid rows

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The height of window is 454. Let's count for ListBox: 10+352=362. Let's count for button: 386+42=428. So, what is oversized? Then why in editor it's not oversized?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204359/discussion-between-johnyl-and-pavel-anikhouski).

Answer (score 1):

You're using a Grid, but you're not positioning things using the Grid.  Your Grid needs to have ColumnDefinitions and/or RowDefinitions, and in the items in the Grid, you need to specify the Grid.Column and/or Grid.Row they're in.

If your UI can be as simple as the above, though, consider using a simpler container such as the DockPanel.  You can set your Button to be positioned at DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" and then your ListBox can fill the remaining space in the DockPanel.

Have a look here for more details, and sample markup, of how to use the Grid and DockPanel:

[Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=netframework-4.8)

[DockPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Same thing happens if I use canvas instead of Grid.

Comment: @JohnyL Using a Canvas would make no sense. Use a Grid as it is supposed to be used, with rows or columns or both.

Comment: @Clemens Tell me why the editor displays correctly?

Comment: @JohnyL Please try what I've suggested above and tell me why it doesn't work, instead of trying something different from what I've suggested and telling me _that_ doesn't work.  It's great that you're trying to write an app with WPF, but there is a bit of a learning curve.  You need to read about the Grid and DockPanel (and others such as StackPanel) and understand how to use them properly.

Answer (score 0):

The Window height (450) is too small to vertically fit all of the content. To avoid using large fixed margins or offset positions, which will easily mess up when the parent window is resized, you can use a lot of the WPF auto-sizing features. For example You can add two rows to host the button and the listbox and you will have a more flexible view:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="10"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Height="42" Width="185"
            Content="TEST BUTTON">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Then how the editor displayed it?

Comment: The title bar at run-time view is clearly taller than the one displayed in the designer. This size is calculated in the total window height, but it is not in taken account in the margin values. Set WindowStyle="None" and what you see might be closer to what you get.